# Non-human diet and toxic substances?

Tags: biology, food

Various creatures have different dietary requirements and different tolerances for various substances. For example, felines need taurine and react poorly to citrus, while humans *need* citrus (some source of vitamin C, anyway). Onions, grapes, chocolate and alcohol are bad for various animals. Birds aren't affected by capsaicin.

This makes me sad.

Let's say I am a brilliant geneticist / wizard / supreme being. Without resorting to permanent changes to the laws of physics / ongoing magic, and without making changes to their normal diets, would it be possible to change *all mammals* so that they can safely eat any food that humans can eat? Does biology somehow necessitate that an animal eating a certain diet, or just certain animals, must be susceptible to certain substances that are (mostly) non-toxic to humans?

---

Notes:

- If it helps, you can ignore bats and anything that lives mainly in the water.
- I'm not talking about eating a human diet in entirety; e.g. cats would still be obligate carnivores and I don't mind if they still need taurine, horses would still mainly eat gress. I just don't want my cats/horses to *die* if they consume a modest amount of chocolate.
- They don't need to eat human *quantities* of food; that would be silly. Similar average lethal doses (mg/kG) is fine.
- This isn't about *chewing* or *digesting* human food. Yes, carnivores may not want to eat much grain because their gut won't be able to break it down well enough, but they should be able to enjoy an occasional chocolate martini.
- They shouldn't be subject to cumulative poisoning from any substance that is not a cumulative poison to humans.

---

Edit (thanks to [John](/users/29409) for a fascinating discussion!): I can live with not accounting for non-"linear" scaling effects being a problem for really small animals. I'm also meddling in sizes, such that my "mice" are closer to maybe 20 kg and my "elephants" are closer to 500 kg. Don't think too hard about the additional effects from this, it's just to say that I can mostly ignore the toxicity problems to the extent that raw size is the main cause.

Comment: chocolate and alcohol are bad for humans too it is just humans have a ridiculously high tolerance for certain toxins, particularly maillard compounds. It is believed to be due to humans adapting to eating cooked food for so long. even among humans digestion varies, milk and peanuts come to mind.

Comment: All food ever is bad for all animals, because food is a living thing that has evolved for million of years to not be eaten... Various animals have various tollerances to various foods... But they are still all bad, some more than others. Your mother's milk is probably the only non toxic thing you ever ate.

Comment: Also being forced to eat specific type of protein doesn't necessarily make an animal carnivorous. It's prefered diet does.  By your logic we humans are obligsted algae eaters because we die without fatty acids found only in algae or fish who ate those specific algae.

Comment: to be clear only mammals are effected by capsaicin, it is mammal specific toxin.

Comment: @user81643 source? because there are plenty of human populations that don't eat fish.

Comment: @John omega 3 is the only essential fatty acid humans need to survive. It is only produced in significant quantities by algae, you also find it scarcely in wallnut or flaxseed oil but on contact with air or after cooking it is destroyed or goes rancid. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega-3_fatty_acid also the more omega 6 you eat... The less omega 3 you can absorb. And omega 6 is found in most frying oils and meats.

Comment: @user81643 Omega−3 fatty acids are widely distributed in both plant and animal life, algae have the highest concentration but that is very different than the only significant source. there are thousands of sources including the common chicken egg and most seeds.

Comment: So basically you want that for all substances and all animals, the tolerance for that substance by that animal is greater than or equal to the tolerance a median human would have for said substance?

Comment: @user81643: Those would be omega **minus** three and omega **minus** six. Explanation: in a fatty acid, the carbon atoms are counted starting with 1 at the COOH head. Since various fatty acids have a different number of carbon atoms, the convention is to call the last one "omega". Omega minus three fatty acids are polyunsaturated fatty acids, with a double (= unsaturated) bond between the 3rd and the 4th carbon atom from the end. There are *several* omega minus three fatty acids; the only essential one in healthy people is the alpha-linoleic acid, which is common in all vegetable oils.

Comment: @MartinvanIJcken, something like that, *by mg/Kg*. (Obviously a 50 g mouse is going to have problems eating a 100 g chocolate bar, while that would be nothing to a human. "Equal" would be said mouse eating 50 mg of chocolate vs. a 100 kg human eating 100 g of chocolate, i.e. 1000 mg/Kg in both cases.) Though, as mentioned elsewhere, I can live with this only working for animals greater than a certain size, so long as it could conceivably work for e.g. a 20 kg "mouse".

Comment: The only possible way to solve the problem is to find *why* each specific species of interest cannot eat each specific food you are interested in. For example, cats and dogs cannot each much chocolate because their livers are quite inefficient at metabolizing [theobromine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theobromine_poisoning), which makes the lethal dose considerably smaller than in humans (about 3 times smaller in dogs, and about 5 times smaller in cats.) Combined with the small body mass of a cat, the small lethal dose means that cats get theobromine poisoning at tiny amounts of chocolate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It's all about toxins

First, they already kind of can eat anything in very small doses. Almost all animals have the ability to metabolize small amounts of things that we would say they "can't eat" but the devil is in the dose. So to solve this you could either

a. Upgrade the livers and kidneys of all the animals so that they can more easily handle the toxins.

b. Make the plants and other food sources produce less toxins. But this might make the caffeinated beverage people mad because caffeine is one of these toxins.

Comment: With sufficient waste management it’s possible to metabolise nearly anything.

Comment: @John, again, this is not about animals eating a human diet. This is *just* about them not dying because they ate a modest quantity of something that would be harmless to humans in similar (mg/Kg) quantity. For example, a dog eating an occasional chocolate bar or a couple onion rings, or a cat eating a grape or a slice of an orange. A cat eating a *whole* orange should be about as dangerous as eating a similar quantity of, say, blueberries... which might still be unhealthy for various other reasons.

Comment: @Matthew I can see you edited your question to be more clear, please don't be upset at posts that came out before your edit.

Comment: Assuming "upgrade the livers and kidneys" is possible, does this take care of pretty much everything humans can eat that animals can't? Are there any weird exceptions to your knowledge? That is, toxicity of allium, theobromine, grapes all comes down to the kidneys/livers not being able to break these down, and you aren't aware of any reason why "make the kidneys/livers better" is implausible?

Comment: @John, I did try to clarify, I think you may have missed my footnote though. Ah, well, no worries, maybe just a footnote was too subtle...

Comment: @Matthew it was your comments about taurine and citrus that threw me off, that is about vitamin production not toxin resistance.

Comment: changing liver enzyme production is not too hard, their livers may end up a little larger. humans have very acidic stomachs which combines with our wide range of enzyme production make it very plausible. You will still run into the size problem, humans get around many toxins just because we are big. Small animals will always run into more toxin sensitivity.

Comment: @John, yeah, that more something I don't need to *also* fix. As to size, *just out of curiosity*, does that affect mean lethal dose? Obviously, 1mg of X might kill a rat and be harmless to a human, but would 10 mg of X be harmless to a 100 kg human while being harmless while 100 µg of X will kill a 1 kg whatever? If so, why? It's not really an issue for me since this is actually world building for a world of anthropomorphic animals; my "mice" are (at least) the size of human children, but I'm curious how that would work.

Comment: @Matthew yes it changes relative dose. to use simple number for clarity 1 kg might be safe for a 100lg human but even 1/1000 might be lethal to a 1kg mouse. biochemical scaling is not a straight volumetric function. Now child sized is a lot closer to human sized so dosage is much closer to normal mass scaling. expect the dangerous dosage for a child sized being (25kg) to be between a quarter and a tenth of the dose of an adult human. there are several reasons for this including the square cube law and non linear metabolic scaling.